# Перебрать все значения

Tags: php

[image]

Есть в форме таблица с инпутами name="800x400", name="800x500". Думаю, смысл понятен.

В обработчике я же не буду для каждого значения прописывать $_POST['800x400'] и т.д. Как сделать циклом, чтобы вывести их автоматически?
Обратите внимание, что в первом столбце значение 900 отсутствует, т.е. шаг 100 туда не подойдет.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переберите все значения циклом

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
  $coord = explode('x', $key);
  var_dump($coord, $val);
}
```

---

**Update**

А если инпутам давать имена не `800x400`, а `cell[800][400]`, то и цикл и `explode` не нужен

```
var_dump($_POST['cell']);
```

Comment: А у меня там не только эта табличка.

Comment: Как мне сделать так, чтобы $title = $_POST['title'] и т,д. в цикле проставлялись автоматически?

Comment: Что значит - проставлялись автоматически?

Comment: Ну вот сейчас так
$title = $_POST['title'];
$descr = $_POST['descr'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
и т.д.
а мне нужно, чтобы это было автоматом

Comment: И как бы сюда это всё дело автоматом $add = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `products` (`title`, `descr`, `price`, `imgs`, `date`, `cat`, `type`) VALUES ('{$title}', '{$descr}', '{$price}', '{$imgs}', '{$date}', '{$cat}', '{$type}');");

Comment: Извините, придется писать код

Comment: Дайте мне направление хотя бы

Comment: Если моего ответа на ваш вопрос недостаточно - задайте уточнение. Если у вас появился новый вопрос - задайте его в отдельной теме